# No audio through monitor speakers when connected through DP on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers

I've connected a Windows laptop through the same displayport cable and the audio worked fine. If I connect my Ubuntu 20.04 computer however, the speakers output no sound. Plugging in earphones work fine though. The monitor is LG 32UD59-B. My graphics card from which I'm connecting the DP is a R9 280 I believe.

I've gone through Alsamixer and played around with pretty much every permutation. I've also played around in Pavucontrol.
[Something odd is that pavucontrol says that audio is playing through the display port, however, the speakers emit no sound.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ahYy.png)

Something odd that I found in Alsamixer is that [I have an extra soundcard for HDMI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhb9N.png)?
[Though when I go into it, it's pretty empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRFOA.png).

Comment: If you go to the Ubuntu settings app (Sound) what Output Device is selected and what Output Devices are in the list? Have you tried the `Test` on the different output devices? I only ask as I have a similar setup and Pavucontrol can look o.k. but the Ubuntu output devices are different and I need to select the right one there. Also on some wakes from suspend I find the output device I need is weirdly missing from Ubuntu settings, so I get no sound.

Comment: The output device is set to HDMI/DisplayPort - Tahiti HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7870 XT/ 7950/7970.
Clicking on test and a speaker shows the bar move up as if there's audio, but the speakers play no sound.
Thank you nevertheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My graphics card recently died and I got myself a GTX 1060. The audio now works...I suppose the DP out on the R9 280 either doesn't work properly, or it was broken on my model.

This isn't the most helpful of solutions "just get a new graphics card", but if you have a friend with a different graphics card, try it out and see if it's your settings or the DP port.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a NUC using Intel card sound with ALC256. Similar results to yours: Pavu says something is played but no sound coming through HDMI.
After a very long search, I could eliminate the problem in 2 steps (not sure if the first was necessary):

1. Update the BIOS following Intel's instructions (see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005636/intel-nuc.html)
2. Go to the BIOS configuration (pressing F2 on startup) and in 'Advanced -> Devices -> Onboard Devices', activate the 'Audio DSP' (page 25 of this manual: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/intel-nuc/NUC-Visual-BIOS-Glossary.pdf

Comment: I don't think I have a NUC computer. I have an i5-4670k and a standard motherboard (asrock z something, don't remember).

I checked the BIOS nevertheless and found no option for Audio DSP (which makes sense, not the same BIOS). Unfortunately didn't work for me, awesome that you got it to work for yourself though!